# Expand homography matrix for distortion

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, transformation, homography

I have two set of corresponding matches that I want to compute Homography Matrix between them. However, I found that the transformation between this points can not be modeled using just the Homography Matrix. I figured this by observing some lines in the original set of points have not represented as lines in the second set.

**For example:**

[image]

The previous state is very extreme in real the distortion is much less than that. It is usually a distortion because of the first set of points were extracted from image that was taken by scanner where the other set of points were extracted from a photo taken by mobile phone.

**The Question:**

How can I expand or Generalize the Homography matrix to make it includes this case? Or in other words, I want a **non-line-preserve transformation model** to use it instead of the Homography Matrix, Any Suggestion?

P.S OpenCV library is prefered if there is something ready to use.

**EDIT:**

Eliminating the distortion may not be an option for me because the photos are somewhat complex and I do not have the same Camera always plus I supposed to deal with images from unknown source (back-end separated from front-end). However, I have a reference which is planner and a query which has perspective + distoration effect which I want to correct it after I could found the corresponding pair matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you had provided some examples of your images, so that we can understand your case better. From the description it seems that you are dealing with [camera distortion](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html).

Typical approach is to perform camera calibration once, then undistort each frame and finally work with images where straight lines look straight. All of these tasks are possible with OpenCV, consider the link above.

In case you cannot perform camera calibration to estimate distortion - there isn't much you can do. Try to calculate and apply homography on unrectified images - if the cameras don't have wide angle lens this should look ok (consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263461/camera-calibration-and-birds-eye-projection-in-opencv) case for example)

Comment: Thanks, eliminate the distortion may not be an option for me because the photos are somewhat complex and I do not have the same Camera always plus I supposed to deal with images from unknown source. (back-end separated from front-end). However, I have a reference which is planner and a query which has perspective + distoration effect which I want to correct it

Comment: Thanks, I still believe that there is a model between plane image and the distorted image. Finally, it was distorted because of some transformation so the inverse of this transformation should be exist.

Comment: That inverse may(or may not) exist, but you may have too few data to estimate it, especially if transformation is complex

Comment: Consider this: for homography estimation you need 4 exact correspondences or more if they are inexact. To perform distortion coefficient estimation theoretically you need at least 2 snaphots of a calibration pattern with many detected keypoints, but in practice you'll need >= 10 good frames with pattern in different positions. And you want to estimate 2 transformations jointly using only one frame with uncalibrated camera, without any reliable image formation model. This seems hopeless to me.

Comment: I have a good amount of pairs. more than 200 with less than 10% outliers. if there is no distoration I am getting more than perfect homography. The problem in distoration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98196/discussion-between-user3896254-and-humam-helfawi).